How to skip stages in gitlab?
I am looking for a solution to find out that is there a way to skip bulid and test stage when changes are made in helm?
may be a rule or a condition?
I want to run deploy and release stage only so using [skip ci] in commit wont work for me .
any solution ?
I am expecting a rule or a condition where i can skip few stages when changes are in helm repo only

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
